# MySql Binary query

Tags: mysql, sql, binary

I have a table with a Binary PK:

```
CREATE TABLE `codes` (
   `Code` binary(45) NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (`Code`),
   UNIQUE KEY `Code_UNIQUE` (`Code`)

 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I insert I use `BINARY('value')`.

I attempted to retrieve a row by `Code` using the following:

```
SELECT * from codes WHERE `Code` = BINARY('value')
```

This doesn't work because the length of the `Code` field is 45, so MySql pads the data with empty bytes.

This can be visualised running the following:

```
SELECT HEX(Code), HEX(BINARY('value')) FROM codes
```

[image]

I can get it to work with this (ugly) query:

```
SELECT * FROM codes WHERE TRIM('0' from HEX(Code)) = HEX(BINARY('value'))
```

So I was just wondering if anyone can provide a nice and performant way to achieve this. This is straightforward if you know the size of your data, but the `Code` field can be any length.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data showcasing this. A DB / SQL fiddle would be handy.

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya Updated with a screenshot

Comment: Images never help! Because we cannot reproduce the case. You can either provide us with the DDL statements for your table(s); or it would be even better if you can directly provide a https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3eqCCdEQPsiuxhjef2xHtb/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [`Binary`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) datatype, you should use [`Varbinary`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html). This will not pad the data with trailing 0s, in case the length of data is smaller than the maximum size defined.

> When BINARY values are stored, they are right-padded with the pad
>   value to the specified length. The pad value is 0x00 (the zero byte).
>   Values are right-padded with 0x00 on insert, and no trailing bytes are
>   removed on select.
>
> For VARBINARY, there is no padding on insert and no bytes are stripped
>   on select.

Also, you do not need to define Unique constraint on an already defined Primary Key. Primary Key basically satisfied the Unique constraint, with additional condition of `NOT NULL` values. So, defining Unique constraint further does not add anything upon it.

This is how the `CREATE TABLE` statement can be:

```
CREATE TABLE `codes` (
   `Code` Varbinary(45) NOT NULL, -- Changed to Varbinary

   PRIMARY KEY (`Code`) -- Removed Unique constraint

 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into codes (Code) VALUES (BINARY('value'));
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT HEX(Code), HEX(BINARY('value')) FROM codes ;

| HEX(Code)  | HEX(BINARY('value')) |
| ---------- | -------------------- |
| 76616C7565 | 76616C7565           |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * from codes WHERE `Code` = BINARY('value');

| Code            |
| --------------- |
| [object Object] |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3eqCCdEQPsiuxhjef2xHtb/1)